# Libgdx animate letters dynamically

Tags: animation, libgdx

I want to animate any random text like this gif

[image]

How can I animate letters like this or animate differently. I just want to make letters more lively. Any other animation will also work, I want the approach for animating letters like in after effects. But After effects animation will be imported as a picture. I want to apply animation on any given text.

Edit:
@Tenfour04

I tried applying shader on red gradient image as you mentioned, but no luck, shader is rendering white image.

[image]

I got black and white image :(

[image]

My render and create function:

```
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
    t = new Texture("grad.png");
    shader = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("vert.vert"), Gdx.files.internal("frag.frag"));

    sprite=new Sprite(t);

}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(time<1)
    time+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    else time=0;

    shader.begin();
    shader.setUniformf("u_progress",time);
    shader.end();

    batch.enableBlending();
    batch.begin();
    batch.setShader(shader);
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();

}
```

My fragment shader:

```
void main() {
    vec4 tex = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
    float opacity = step(tex.r, u_progress);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, v_color.a * tex.a * opacity);
}
```

P.S. This is my first custom shader, so have no idea what has gone wrong.

Comment: You'll have to pre-process each character of your font. What you need to do is make one channel of the image a gradient along the path you want to "draw" at runtime. You'll need to find a way to do that in a drawing program like Gimp. So the red channel could be a gradiant from 0 to 255 along the path, and leave alpha unmodified. You can assemble all the letter images into a BittmapFont using the free app Shoebox.

Comment: In the game use a custom shader that has a uniform float for animation progress from 0 to 1. In the fragment shader use `float opacity = step(tex.r, u_progress); gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, v_color.a * texture.a * opacity);`

Comment: @Tenfour04 I cannot understand the thing about gradient. Could you please elaborate a bit. How will it help in tracing along path?

Comment: Imagine a simple texture that is black on the left and blends to pure red on the right. If your shader has a uniform value between 0 and 1, and you use it with the red color in the texture in a step function, it will cause a percentage of the texture to be visble, while the rest is visible. For example, if you use `step(u_progress, tex.r)`, and `u_progress` is 0.25, then the first 25% of the texture will evaluate to 0 and the last 75% of the texture will evaluate to 1. Then you can multiply this number by the opacity. And you can animate the uniform to achieve the sweep effect.

Comment: @Tenfour04, your solution is working but the texture is whitewashed, tried everything but cant figure out. Please help. Sorry i am a newbie in shader :)

Comment: Your shader is perfect. This is the expected outcome since your source texture has 100% alpha all over and you haven't changed the color in the SpriteBatch. If you use `setColor` on the `sprite` before drawing it, you should see that color.

Comment: Try an image like this where there is shape in the alpha channel. https://imgur.com/a/08BAQRV

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear. We are not using the texture color for defining the color of the sprite. We are only using the red channel of the texture to encode the animation and we are using the alpha channel normally. The final color of the letter will be defined by vertex colors. When you do this with actual text, you can use LibGDX color markup to use various colors in your text string: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Color-Markup-Language

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanx a lot, you cleared many doubts and gave tons of information ;). One last question, can you suggest alternative for shoebox, it wont work in linux.

Comment: I've never looked for any alternatives.